# Anaconda 'pip install scipy' installs an incomplete version of the package

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I'm having a strange error installing scipy on an anaconda environment. Specifically, I've setup my environment to use Python 2.7.12, and to install a number of other packages (which, as far as I've tested, seem fine). But I'm having a problem with scipy in specific, in that when I type "pip install scipy" or any variant of that (while my environment is activated), it seems to install an incomplete version of the package.

For example, I typed `pip install -Iv scipy==0.17.0`, opened Python, and ran

```
>>> import scipy
>>> module = type(scipy)
>>> print [x for x in dir(scipy) if type(getattr(scipy, x)) == module]
```

the output of which is

```
['__config__', '_lib', 'add_newdocs', 'char', 'ctypeslib', 'emath', 'ma', 'math', 'random', 'rec', 'version']
```

Now, if I run that same code on my non-anaconda python environment, I get the following output

```
['__config__', '_lib', 'add_newdocs', 'char', 'ctypeslib', 'emath', 'integrate', 'linalg', 'ma', 'math', 'misc', 'ndimage', 'random', 'rec', 'sparse', 'special', 'version']
```

So clearly, I'm missing `scipy.integrate`, `scipy.linalg`, `scipy.misc`, `scipy.ndimage`, `scipy.sparse`, and `scipy.special`. Note that `scipy.__version__` is the same in both environments, `0.17.0`.

Why is this happening? Why am I missing scipy submodules on my anaconda environment?

Comment: If you're in an anaconda environment, why install scipy with pip instead of conda?

Comment: You possibly are missing system packages for libraries that scipy uses for optional components. Check what system packages are required for scipy. See https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/linux.html#generic-instructions